# How to reset the font in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts, resolution

I installed a software: JAWS screen reader. And it did something with my font or screen resolution and the words started looking pixelated. I uninstalled that program and restarted the pc but the words still looks pixelated.

I tried searching on how to fix this so I then did reset the font settings of my pc but still it looks same. My screen resolution is also the same as before. Attaching a screenshot: 
Now: 
[image]

Earlier: 
[image]

I'm unable to understand what exactly is wrong. Is it the font settings or is it something related to screen resolution or the graphics card. Do anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: You should run `Clear Type Text tuner`. this is inbuilt windows feature.

Comment: @Sandeep I did try that but it doesn't change anything. Moreover I'm not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: It's definitely disabled ClearType. The font hasn't changed, but it isn't smoothed.

Comment: Restarting after running clearType reflected the changes. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem no longer can be reproduced.

Comment: @Sandeep Consider adding your suggested solution as an answer indicating perhaps a power cycle after the suggested solution is completed since the OP indicates your solution with a power cycle resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should run `Clear Type Text tuner` to resolve this problem. This is inbuilt windows feature. [Here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-text-easier-read-using-cleartype-windows-10) is a post on `Windows Central` with step by step guide to setup this feature.

**What is Clear Type Text feature**

> ClearType font technology was developed by Microsoft specifically to improve the readability of text on LCD screens, like the one on your laptop, tablet, and desktop monitor. Using ClearType will smooth the edges of the words on your device making them sharp and clear, very close to what you see printed out on a piece of paper.

**How to use ClearType Text Tuner**

1. Open Start, do a search for `Adjust ClearType text` and click the result.
2. Make sure to check the Turn on `ClearType` option and click Next.
3. If you have multiple monitors, you'll be asked whether you want to tune all your displays or only one. If this is your case, it's recommended that you enable ClearType on every monitor. Make your selection and click `Next` to continue.
4. Windows will also check that your monitor is using its native resolution. (If this isn't the case, you'll have to go to `Settings > Display > Advanced Display` Settings and check the screen resolution to recommended settings.) Click `Next` to continue.
5. On a set of five samples, you'll be asked to select the text that you feel most comfortable reading. The highlighted text is the current settings for your device. Pick the text that looks best on each sample, and click `Next`.
6. If you have multiple monitors, you'll need to run the same set of steps for each monitor. Once you completed the steps, click `Finish` to apply the new settings.